# Receive currency prices and perform calculations on prices

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I want to show the user the price of digital currencies in a list.
And for example, prices are updated every 5 seconds.
Now I have a problem, maybe I have 100 types of currencies and when the user enters the prices page, the price of each currency must be received to be displayed to the user and before the display, the price is calculated (because the sale price and Specify the purchase for each currency).
Now I think this will be very heavy and may cause the user to wait too long for the page to load
What is your solution? How do I handle this?
I use Laravel and livewire

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebSockets to update the prices in real-time. You just need to keep broadcasting to the channel with the new prices. You can use [laravel WebSockets](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/getting-started/introduction) or [larasocket](https://larasocket.com/) or [pusher](https://pusher.com/). Or any other websocket method. checkout [Websockets MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)